# Is SmartPy package inside All Michaelson Supported Languages?

Tags: smartpy, liquidity, ligo

I've discovered that Liquidity, LigoLang and Ocamel Support Tezos development, but I've only found 1 resource that states that SmartPy supports only LigoLang. I wanted to use the right language to begin my teams project, but we all have experience writting in Python. We know that Liquidity offers a lot of Backend Support but we can't find any way to download SmartPy into our IDE.

Are we not using the right IDE? what IDE supports Both Liquidity and LigoLang Documentation ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

SmartPy is a smart-contract programming language on its own. You can use the [Online IDE](https://smartpy.io/ide) or use your local IDE and test the contracts with the CLI.

You can find more information here: [Help Section](https://smartpy.io/help)

Example contract: [Example](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmTGtBdiUyZoNiWeoSgR3FvtZmCMoLDFJmZjdFKByS1kjD&k=6aae0b8d3146857fab92)

**Side note:** Both SmartPy and Ligo languages allow you to compile to Michelson, neither of them depends on each other.